Exercise 2.6 in Katok's book "Fuchsian Groups"
Exercise 2.6 in Svetlana Katok's book Fuchsian Groups asserts the following

Let $G$ be a subgroup of isometries of a proper metric space $X$. Then the following are equivalent:
(i)/(ii) The action is properly discontinuous: namely for each compact subset $K$ there are only finitely many $T\in G$ with $T(K)\cap K \neq \emptyset$.
(iii) For each $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ for which the conditions $T\in G$ and $T(V)\cap V\neq V$ imply $T(x)=x$.

I can get (ii) implies (iii) but not vice versa. In particular, I cannot even understand why condition (iii) implies that the stabilizer of $x$ in $G$ is finite which would imply the conclusion by Theorem 2.2.1 in the same book. I am not sure if I am missing something or if this is another typo in a book with many of them.

As written, (iii) does not imply (ii). For instance, consider the trivial action of an infinite group on a nonempty space. (There are more intresting examples as well.) As for the opposite direction, yes and my answer in the link does the job.

@MoisheKohan I edited to require that $G<Isom(X)$ so nothing actually acts trivially.

It is still false, just think of $X$ with an isolated point fixed by the entire $G$ and $G$ acting properly on the rest of the space.

There are many mistakes in Katok's discussion of proper discontinuity and in other places. The implication (iii)$\Rightarrow$(i) holds for faithful isometric group actions on connected Riemannian manifolds and this suffices for what she does in the book.

Here is a counter-example to the implication (iii)$\Rightarrow$(i). Consider $\mathbb R$ with the metric
$$
d(x,y)=\min\{ |x-y|, 1\}. 
$$
Let $X=\mathbb R\times \{0,1\}$ denote the disjoint union of two copies of $\mathbb R$, each equipped with the metric $d$ as above, where
$$
d((x,i), (y,j))=1, i\ne j, x, y\in \mathbb R. 
$$
Consider the action of $G=\mathbb Z$ on $X$ which is trivial on $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$ and which is the standard action by integer translations on $\mathbb R\times \{1\}$. This action is clearly faithful, isometric and satisfies Katok's condition (iii). However, the action obviously fails to be properly discontinuous.
There are several ways to correct the erroneous claim. For instance, one can prove that it holds for geodesic metric spaces. Also, you do not need properness of the metric space.
Here is a rule of thumb when you find a claim in Katok's book without a proper proof:
Add the assumption that  the space in question is the hyperbolic plane, the group action is isometric, and, when dealing with fundamental domains, that the latter are convex. Also, consult Beardon's "Geometry of discrete groups."
